# How can I use code to "hide" content at it's own URL (result is blank page), BUT show it normal in an iFrame at another URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to use the code inline. I own all the domains including where the iFrame is used and I can access all file types. The source is created with HTML and the iFrame is on wordpress.

This redirect script works fine

```
function check_frame() {
     if( top === self ) { // not in a frame
          location.href = "https://any.com"; // either the frameset or an error.
}
    }
```

This script is what I can't figure out (if source is loaded in iFrame, it should appear as normal in the iFrame)

```
function check_frame() {
     if( top !== self ) { //  in a frame
          document.body.classList.add('framed');
}     

     }
```

This works, I tried to leave it out and my redirect failed.

```
<body onLoad="check_frame()">
</body>
```

This works (yes, I want nothing visible on the source of the iFrame IF it is accessed outside of an iFrame, to have a display:none would even be better but I am not sure that's possible since I need it to appear in the iFrame).

~ if interested why I want this: If a client accidentally stumbles to the source then they see their content load for a second before the redirect happens. I want to avoid them seeing anything. ~

HOWEVER- This is also how my iFrame appears (not visible). Which is not what I want.

```
<style>
body {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This doesn't work along with the script above that doesn't work.

```
body.framed {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

I am open to other work around suggestions, Just keep in mind I have to do any HTML, CSS and JS inline for the source page and the iFrames will be on wordpress). I own ALL domains I am working with. Please specify if your suggestions will work cross(sub)-domain or not. Thanks!!!